# Apache Camel looses CRLF when writing to SFTP server

Tags: apache-camel, newline, sftp

When writing a text file to a SFTP serveur via Apache Camel (and via Talend ESB), the file on the server looses CRLF, it only contains LF.

It works if we use FTP mode instead of SFTP.

It fails in SFTP mode with "&binary=true", with "&binary=false" and whatever the SFTP server we connect to.

It works on the same SFTP servers if we manually transfer the file with Filezilla.

Is there any workaround for what looks like a Camel bug ?

Comment: What SFTP server are you using?

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't belong to me. A linux system, I guess...

Comment: Have you tried to upload a file with any SFTP client? Is there any problems in uploaded file via SFTP client? If yes, then it's probably a problem in SFTP server settings.